# Running Entity Framework build

Tags: entity-framework, build

I'm running the Entity Framework installation with

```
build /t:RestorePackages
```

But I get this output:

```
Building C:\Github\EntityFramework-dev
dotnet-install: .NET SDK version 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is already installed.
Adding C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\ to PATH
Using makefile: makefile.shade
fail: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
fail: Stack trace:
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Sake.Engine.Builder.BuilderBase`1.CallTarget(String name)
   at Sake.Engine.SakeEngine.Execute(Options options)
   at Sake.Engine.SakeEngine.Execute(String[] args)
   at Sake.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I played with the build file, and apparently the line originating the error is `use-standard-lifecycle` in the makefile.shade.
If I remove it I get several errors, like

```
fail: Dynamic view compilation failed.
c:\Github\EntityFramework-dev\makefile.shade(10,30): error CS0103: The name 'E' does not exist in the current context
c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\7e99278fc8ad4d268bcdb4b2693a6f36-1.cs(92,9): error CS0103: The name 'BuildQuality' does not exist in the current context
```

I tried reading info on sake, but could not identify the reason. Any hint?

Comment: Can you share makefile.shade content ?

Comment: Here is the makefile.shade - https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/makefile.shade